# Difference between pg-promise 'duration' and execution time in EXPLAIN ANALYSE of postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pg-promise

I am using 'duration' property from data object of 'result' function to measure the duration of execution of my query.

I tried the same query in pgAdmin with "EXPLAIN ANALYSE".

Both have a big difference.

can anyone say why is this?

which is the right approach to measure the execution duration of my query.

Comment: Could you provide more details about the `Both have a big difference.`?

Comment: execution time of a query duration provided by method result of pg-promise is 85ms and EXPLAIN ANALYSE is 30ms

Answer (score 0):

`EXPLAIN ANALYSE` is a performance perspective internal to the server only.

`duration` provided by method [result](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.result) of `pg-promise` includes:

- preparing the query for execution
- sending the query into the server
- receiving and parsing the query by the server
- executing the query (your `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` duration)
- serializing the data and sending the response back
- receiving data by the client
- deserializing and converting data into JSON
- notifying your code about the data

That's where the difference comes from.

Comment: I have written a gulp task to measure execution duration in which i print the duration field of result method as the query execution time. But i cannot find any difference the duration time after and before indexing where as i can find the difference when i run EXPLAIN ANALYSE In pgAdmin