# Speed-up query by decreasing duration time

Tags: node.js, postgis, pg-promise

I use pg-promise to query a postgis database containing rasters. Queries are strings (with no parameters) generated before being processed by pg-promise.

The duration time of one query is typically 140ms (given by result function), while only 15ms in psql.

Example:

```
SELECT ST_Value(t_2m_1, ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(5,50),4326)) AS t_2m_1 FROM iconeu_001 WHERE ST_Intersects(t_2m_1,ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(5,50),4326));

Results: [ { t_2m_1: 4.61391601562502 } ] Duration: 147ms
```

While timing in psql:

```
      t_2m_1
------------------
 4.61391601562502
(1 row)

Time: 15.828 ms
```

It means that 90% of time is spent by pre and post processing the query as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38639898/4340559).

Also, is there any way of dramatically speed up this steps (by skipping some unneeded steps for instance) ??

Thanks in advance.

PS: congratulations to vitaly-t for this excellent module !

Comment: You can execute multiple queries as one, via method [multi](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi). And you can automatically join them, using [helpers.concat](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.concat).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately some of queries have to be executed one by one. For the ones that can be joined, I use task+batch method. Is it faster to use multi ?

Comment: `Is it faster to use multi?` - dramatically. That's one query request versus multiple. However, in 99% the performance issue you reported isn't real when it comes to real-world applications. Your measuring is likely skewed by a few x-factors.